# Make Pop-up scrollable

Tags: html, css

Wanted to know how to make the pop up scroll able.

The content in the pop-up gets clipped in the mobile screen

On desktop it displays well. But on the mobile device only background get scrolled and not the pop-up

```css
.overlay {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  transition: opacity 500ms;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
}
.overlay:target {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}

.popup {
  margin: 70px auto;
  padding: 20px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 30%;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 5s ease-in-out;
}


.popup .close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 30px;
  transition: all 200ms;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #333;
}

.popup .content {
  max-height: 30%;
  overflow: auto;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 700px){
  .popup{
    width: 70%;
  }
```

```html
 <span><a href="#popup">Full Recipe</a></span>
          <div id="popup" class="overlay">
    <div class="popup">
        <h3>Foxtail Millet Porridge:</h3>
        <a class="close" href="#">×</a>
        <div class="content">
            <span>Ingredients:</span>
```

Thank you for your help !

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Sacd.jpg)

Comment: Set the overflow on the popup, not on the content.

Comment: HI  Michel, thank you for your comment, it still does not scroll. It gets clipped at the bottom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The content had too big of a height and wouldn't allow scrolling.

Here is the Codepen for the [full code](https://codepen.io/smishydev/pen/BaYgbpm?editors=1100)

```
.popup {
  transform: translateY(-60px); /* moves container up the page */
  margin: 70px auto;
  padding: 20px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 30%;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 5s ease-in-out;
}
.content {
  height: 250px; /* adjust this depending on the size that you want the 
                    container to be */
}
.popup .content {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Comment: hi Smishy, when you put in too much content it get clipped at the bottom of the screen.

Comment: I have added an image to the question

Comment: I've edited my original answer with the updated code, that should answer your question

Comment: Thank you for your help Smishy, This works. Also is there a way to stop background scrolling when pop-up is open